# How to find list contains any value from another list and make combine list using scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have following two lists -

```
list1 = List(("jira","ABC"),
             ("collApp","ABC"),
             ("amarColl","ABC"),
             ("Ubuntu1404","PQR"),
             ("relColAdmin","XYZ"))

list2 = List(("Linux_server","Hyper-V","suseLinux"), 
             ("Linux_server","VmWare","collApp"), 
             ("Linux_server","VmWare","relColAdmin"), 
             ("Linux_server","VmWare","amarColl"),
             ("Linux_server","Hyper-V","ubuntu1310"))
```

From above tow lists I want to check if second list contains first value of each element(tuple) of list1 and if matched insert second value in list2 otherwise insert empty value in list2.

Here is sample output -

```
output = List(("Linux_server","Hyper-V","suseLinux",""),
              ("Linux_server","VmWare","collApp","ABC"),
              ("Linux_server","VmWare","relColAdmin","XYZ"),
              ("Linux_server","VmWare","amarColl","ABC"),  
              ("Linux_server","Hyper-V","ubuntu1310",""))
```

Comment: " insert second value in list2 otherwise insert empty value in list2." Note the elements are not lists, but tuples. It doesn't really make sense to "insert" an element in a tuple, since the result is a different type. Is there some reason why tuples are required here? (there are many similar questions here, so I assume this is an assignment from a course?)

Answer (score 5):

list1 is already in perfect form for turning into a map. We'll turn it into a map that has a default value of "". So that if we request a key from the map that doesn't exist, we get back ""

```
scala> val map1 = list1.toMap.withDefaultValue("")
map1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = 
    Map(amarColl -> ABC, Ubuntu1404 -> PQR, relColAdmin -> XYZ,
        jira -> ABC, collApp -> ABC)
```

now all we have to do is map the 3-tuple to a 4-tuple:

```
scala> list2.map { case (a,b,c) => (a,b,c,map1(c)) }
res0: List[(String, String, String, String)] = 
   List((Linux_server,Hyper-V,suseLinux,""),
        (Linux_server,VmWare,collApp,ABC), 
        (Linux_server,VmWare,relColAdmin,XYZ), 
        (Linux_server,VmWare,amarColl,ABC),
        (Linux_server,Hyper-V,ubuntu1310,""))
```

Answer (score 1):

If first element of list1's tuples could be placed in any position of list2's tuples, use follow code:

```
list2.map {
  case (a, b, c) =>
    (a, b, c,
      list1.find(e =>
        Seq(a, b, c).contains(e._1)
      ).map(_._2).getOrElse(""))
}
```

If first element of list1's tuples could be placed in 3rd position of list2's tuples only:

```
list2.map {
  case (a, b, c) =>
    (a, b, c,
      list1.find(_._1 == c)
        .map(_._2).getOrElse(""))
}
```

Comment: This is O(n^2) and could be O(n)

Comment: @stew agree with you. Using `Map` is more efficient in second case.

Answer (score 0):

First, zip them together

```
val zipped = list1 zip list2
```

Then, map over the zipped pairs and build the result

```
val output = zipped.map(case ((key, value), targetTuple) => buildResultTuple(key, value, targetTuple))

def buildResultTuple(key:String, value: String, t:Tuple3):Tuple4 = {
   val l = t.productIterator.toList
   if (l contains key) (t._1, t._2, t._3, value)
   else                (t._1, t._2, t._3, "")
}
```